# Cannot run composer self-update: "The phar signature did not match the file you downloaded"

Tags: php, composer-php

The system is windows10 Enterprise

I installed composer; its version is 2.0.8

My symfony 4.4 does not launch with this version of composer; so I decided to downgrade composer with this command : `composer self-update --1`

But I get error :

> The phar signature did not match the file you downloaded, this means your public keys are outdated or that the phar file is corrupt/has been modified

So how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing:

```
composer self-update --update-keys
```

to update your public keys, and rerun the `self-update` command.

If that doesn't work, your `phar` file is really corrupted, and you'll need to download again. Just grab the appropriate file from the "Manual download" section of the download page and overwrite your local composer copy.

Comment: but I did not download any `phar` file ; I just downloaded the composer installer file. The error is still showing after executing the command you gave. So I should grab a phar file ?

Comment: you can use the installer again, or simply download a phar file and overwrite your existing composer file. for some reason your existing file seems to be corrupt. it could also be a network problem, and sort it self out later on.

Comment: where is the composer file located ?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your system.

Comment: You could also simply download the phar file and execute it directly (`php composer.phar`). Having it installed globally is just a matter of convenience, and if you want to use an older version for some project for X reasons, having a local copy for that project could end up being more convenient.

Comment: I downloaded a phar file and I followed a tutorial on youtube to install manually composer.